# Flex box won't work with doctype HTML 4.0 Transitional

Tags: html, css, flexbox, doctype

I Can't render a flexible box properly on IE 11 but when I replace :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

By

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

That’s work fine.

Can someone tell me why ? here’s a snipped of code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <style> 
            td {
            background: #eee;
            border: 1px solid;
            }

            .flex-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction:column;
            width: 400px;
            height: 250px;
            }

            .flex-item {
            display:block;
            }

            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>normal cell</td>
                <td>normal cell</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- my flexibal container-->
            <tr class="flex-container">
                <td class="flex-item">flex item 1</td>
                <td class="flex-item">flex item 2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The HTML 4.0 doctype will always trigger quirks mode. If you must use a legacy doctype, e.g. because you need to rely on almost standards mode, use the HTML 4.01 doctype, not the HTML 4.0 one:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Otherwise, seriously, just stick to the new doctype.